# Krita Fill Tool Keeps covering everything

Tags: krita

I'm using Krita right now, and every single time I use the fill tool it keeps filling everything not just the space I want it to fill, even the parts that I do not want filled in and it's getting on my nerves. When I make a circle I want just the circle filled up but it keeps covering the whole canvas with the fill tool. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had the same problem, searched online for solutions and found other people suggesting reduce threshold and stuff.

So I went messing with the fill tool option ;then suddenly found out an obvious and simple solution.

> > > UNCHECK everything in the tool option, it should work perfectly fine now :)